# How to convert DateTime to Timestamp before saving in Firestore in Flutter?

Tags: flutter-web

I picked a "date" form datePicker and wanted to save that date (type as DateTime) to Firestore in Timestamp type.
I used Firestore.fromDate(date) but it stores data in Firestore as a map(nanoseconds, seconds).

Comment: `DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch` to store date in int then u can decode it while using https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.2/dart-core/DateTime/millisecondsSinceEpoch.html

Comment: @GJJ2019 Thanks for your help but if there is any way to store date in timestamp, that will be better because the code that our team wrote for react native app is too big now to change data type.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Firebase `Timestamp` class as:

```dart
Timestamp.fromMicrosecondsSinceEpoch(myDateTime.microsecondsSinceEpoch)
```

There are many other constructors, take a look at the docs.