# I am trying to use Date Picker in flutter and store my date into cloud firestore .But my date is showing as null

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, datepicker

I am trying to use Date Picker in flutter  and  store my date into cloud  firestore .But my date is showing  as null

Please explain me how to  store the value of date for example date of expiry , birth date etc  in firebase storage or cloud  fire store and retrive the valuue of date gain from firestore after saving into it in flutter application

My firestore code is as follows

I doubt whether I have to take Warranty Date as string i.e TextEditing Controller etc or any  direct or default method is there.

```
    String WarrantyDate = 'Warranty Date';
 final WarrantyDateController = TextEditingController();
  @override
  void dispose() {
;
   WarrantyDateController.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }

  String _selectDateString;              if (widget.product == null) {
    //New Record

    WarrantyDateController.text= "";



  } else {
    //Controller Update

   WarrantyDateController.text=widget.product.WarrantyDate;


    // priceController.text=widget.product.price.toString();
    //State Update


  }

  super.initState();
}
```

Comment: Please update your post with a relevant example of your code where you are seeing the problem. Also, make sure that your code complies to this [guideline](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It should be minimal, complete, and reproducible.

Comment: I doubt whether I have to take Warranty Date as string i.e TextEditing Controller etc or any  direct or default method is there.                                                                                     String WarrantyDate = 'Warranty Date';
 final WarrantyDateController = TextEditingController();
  @override
  void dispose() {
;
   WarrantyDateController.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }

  String _selectDateString;

Answer (score 0):

Firestore [has its own type](https://github.com/google/built_value.dart/issues/543) **Timestamp** to store **Datetime** data. It's up to you if you wish to store the value as **String** or parse **Datetime** to **Timestamp** before saving it to Firestore.

Comment: Ok thank you  but I want to input from the user i.e not current date but future date  i.e Warranty Date of device or Expiry date of a product etc. In this case How Can I use Timestamp. I think Timestamp is only current Date ?

Comment: Refer to the answer on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61994633/how-to-convert-datetime-to-timestamp-before-saving-in-firestore-in-flutter). Take note that date and time is only precise to microseconds and you can use `Timestamp` class to convert your future date.

Comment: Thank you very much for that can u provide me a sample code, so that I can implement  easily in my code as I have other TextForm Fileds or List Items .

Comment: please provide a short sample code , so that I will add to other list items

Comment: There's not much I can give however I highly suggest you follow the [example](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_datetime_picker/example) of Datepicker from Flutter.

Comment: Thank you very much for that. But I want only the date for example Warranty Date, expiry Date i.e a future Date and I want to store as a List item into firestore and then retrieve it again.

Comment: please explain whether to dispose  eventDate etc in flutter while storing in cloud firestore

Comment: You recommended storing the date as String or Timestamp in Firestore.  Why not store as 'Number' like YYYYMMDD (for example) so that you can do <, >, etc. to get multiple records?